# mercurial workflows when collaborating with people who make errors

Tags: mercurial, workflow

I need to collaborate on a Mercurial repository (let's call it "foo") with some people who are novices at version control in general, Mercurial in particular.

I am trying to come up with a workflow that will enable us to use Mercurial without a lot of extra effort on either their end (confusion) or my end (cleanup).

My concern is that as novices I need to expect them to make errors, and I need to allow them to do so in a controlled way, otherwise they won't use the tool at all because they're too scared. But I don't want a bad change to pollute the repository unnecessarily.

I do not expect them to be able to merge properly or to use the `mq` extension. This is not
 a matter of underestimating them, instead it is a realistic assessment given past experience with SVN and my own experience with Hg.

**Which of the following approaches would make the most sense? Or if there's a better approach, what is it?**

1. We have a repository `foo-submit`, read/writable by all, and a repository `foo-trunk`, readable by all but writable by admins. Users pull from `foo-trunk`, and push changes to `foo-submit`. Cleanup: If I find a good change, I let it through as is; if I find a bad change, I "bypass" it by merging with the previous version.
2. We have a repository `foo-trunk` readable by all, writable by admins. Each user is responsible for maintaining their own clone which is read-accessible to the rest of the team. When someone wants to push a change, they let me know and I pull it from their repository, with proper cleanup as necessary (same as in #1)
3. We have a repository `foo-dev`, read/writable by all, and a repository `foo-trunk`, readable by all but writable by admins. Users pull/push to foo-dev, and work in named branches if they need to do extensive development. I am responsible for performing merges and cleanup. The `foo-trunk` repository is merely for having a "clean" copy that has branches where the tip is always in a good state.

Comment: How many devs are going to be working in these repos?

Comment: good question. 4 or 5 tops; mostly just 2 or 3 (myself included).

Answer (score 2):

Good question, and one that I've never seen a great answer to.

That said, I like option 2. This is the "Pull Request" model used by the Linux Kernel and made popular by GitHub. It allows the admins to act as gatekeepers / reviewers, only allowing good change-sets to get past them when they're happy. If they decide a developer hasn't delivered something worthy, then the pull request is rejected (with reasons). Then the developer can go away, fix up their code / repo, and submit another pull request.

Running a server with something like [RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) on it can help keep on top of pull requests. As things grow you can have lower level gatekeepers that deal with subsystems, and higher level gatekeepers that deal with the whole project.

The bit I've never quite got my head around is what should happen to change-sets that are rejected, and that the developer decides to abandon rather than fix up and try again. They could be closed, but then could possibly appear by mistake as part of a future pull request. They'd be harmless, but possibly confusing. The alternative is stripping them, but that sounds like giving people tools they'll cut themselves on.

---

The other 2 options you give deserve a little comment.

1 is similar to 2. You're still doing a "Pull Request" type flow, but now you have server side branches which mirror the developer's clones. There's little difference and this is how a RhodeCode, GitHub, BitBucket server would let you work, except you don't have to go searching for changes. The server would tell you they're waiting for you to look at.

3 has the problem that everyone's changes are all merged together on `foo-dev` before you get to them. They would start becoming inter-dependent, and cherry-picking is going to be messy. You'd probably end up `graft`ing change-sets on to `foo-trunk` which means you're creating new change-sets with new hashes. When the developers pull those they'll now have the change in two places; their original `foo-dev` version and your grafted `foo-trunk` version. This doesn't sound sustainable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Best way i can think of if you don't want to use mq (understand with the least hassle for you) is to have your dev

1. create their own branch for the current feature being developped
2. merge it back to the main dev branch (or graft/transplant) when it's completed and validated
3. and then close the branch.

In the long term see for them to learn mq, it's not too hard to grasp.

Comment: also, is there anything that makes it obvious why mq helps? I tried it the other day, and it just added complexity (new commands, new concepts, new state to think about, more opportunities for making errors) with no obvious benefit that I could see.

Comment: I haven't used bookmarks yet, so i can't say if it's better/cleaner than named branch. Regarding mq, while it does indeed add new commands/concepts to learn, the amount to learn is very small. one of the benefits of mq is that it allows you to work on different aspect of your application: how many times have you been asked to temporarly work on a different part of your application to solve an issue, while you were currently working on a different part of the same application ? quite often i imagine.

Comment: mq brings you the notion of patches and thus allows you to create cleaner changesets in your commits

Answer (score 1):

3a - `foo-dev` has protected `default` branch  (only some admins can push/merge-to this branch), users use named branches

Comment: good idea... how do you handle per-branch access control? (I'm on bitbucket)

Comment: @JasonS - no ideas... Own (managed) server assumed with ACL extension